# Does Java provide any libraries to find out the most frequent number in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Just for the further explanation of what title means:

```
int[] array = {1,2,1,3,2,1,4};
```

In the array declared above, **1** has occurred 3 times and so does have the max frequency in the array. Does Java provide anything to find that out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the new Java 8 Streaming API for that:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4};
Optional<Integer> max = Arrays.stream(array)    // IntStream
    .boxed()                                    // Stream<Integer>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(), 
        Collectors.counting())
    )                                           // Map<Integer, Long>
    .entrySet()                                 // Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>>
    .stream()                                   // Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>>
    .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue)) // Optional<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>>
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey);                    // Optional<Integer>
```

I commented on every line, what type currently is returned after said line to make it clear with what types we're currently working.

In short, we create a Stream from the array, then we count every occurance of the different integers, then we select the one integer which has the most occurances.

`Optional<Integer>` is returned, because the stream could by empty, altough in your case the optional will always hold a value.

You can extract the value from the optional multiple ways:

1. `int i = max.get()`; which may throw an exception if no value is present
2. `int i = max.orElse(-1)`; which allows you to set a default value

Comment: Works this way and is quite good also but still takes me back to **for loop** which I really don't want to use.

Comment: @OmkarMote What's wrong with `for`-loops? Before Java8 everything was done using them.

Comment: Understood. But still returns an **Optional**, not an **Integer**.

Comment: @LSpillner Before Java8, but no more.

Comment: @OmkarMote and *no more using for-loops* is the wrong way to programm. Most times they are cleaner, easier, faster and more concise. Than using obfuscated streams and functional programming

Comment: Perfect! It worked. Thanks!

Comment: @OmkarMote You're welcome, glad I could help

Comment: that streaming thing is not so performance-friendly. There are algorithms around that does the job in ~n log(n) using a for loop + map and a check for highest frequency ( based on the used capacity in the map construct). IMHO it is an abuse of the streaming API.

Comment: @KarelG you may provide that as an additional answer. I was just too lazy to not use streams ;)

Comment: @Lino, I agree. But, I didn't want to use in this case. I'm already using a for loop for the work I'm doing. If I had used for loop for getting the most frequent number in an array, it would have been nested for loops. And nested for loops make me confused a lot.

Comment: @OmkarMote if nested loops confuse you. You could split up your current approach into multiple methods. Each with only 1 loop. That would clarify whats happening quite easily

Comment: @OmkarMote I am sorry, but I am not going to. We can move this discussion to chat if you wish to ask more questions though.